# How to Add Custom Action To Task List in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, visual-studio-2012, farm-solution

In one of my POC, there is a requirement to create custom action Ribbon menu for Task List. After lot of research I have tried below code snippet in empty module to add custom action.

```
<CustomAction Id="ActionButton" RegistrationId="107" RegistrationType="List" Location="CommandUI.Ribbon" Title="Add a Action button for tasks list">
 <CommandUIExtension>
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Tasks.Actions.Controls._children">
      <Button Id="Ribbon.Tasks.Actions.ActionButton"
              Alt="Perform an action for task items."
              Sequence="10"
              Command="ActionButtonCommand"
              LabelText="Action Button"
              TemplateAlias="o1"
              Image32by32="/_layouts/15/ActionRibbon/img/action-32x32.png"
              Image16by16="/_layouts/15/ActionRibbon/img/delete-all-16x16.png" />
    </CommandUIDefinition>
  </CommandUIDefinitions>
  <CommandUIHandlers>
    <CommandUIHandler Command="ActionButtonCommand" CommandAction="javascript:alert('Whoa..! You performed an action!');">
    </CommandUIHandler>
  </CommandUIHandlers>
</CommandUIExtension>
```

I have made sure that `RegistrationId`  for Tasks list is `107`. Also checked this Location for `CommandUIDefinitation`.

When I try to add the same custom action to the any of the task list from SharePoint designer and specify the location `Ribbon.Tasks.Actions.Controls._children`.
Custom Action does appear but, when I do the same with Visual studio as farm solution, custom action does not appear at all.

Can some one help me? It would be great help. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you run InPrivate or do CTRL+F5 so that the ribbon isn't fetched from the browser cache

Comment: Thank you for response Steven. Yes, I have tried that too many times. Also when I try to change the target list to custom list by changing RegistrationId to 100 and change location accordingly, it does work. Only case here it is not working for Task list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, After digging lot into web I found out that the `RegistrationID` for Tasks List is `171` from this [link](http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint-2013/extending-sharepoint-2013-ribbon-using-visual-studio), so below code block has worked for me:

```
<CustomAction Id="ActionButton" RegistrationId="171" RegistrationType="List" Location="CommandUI.Ribbon" Title="Add a Action button for tasks list">
 <CommandUIExtension>
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Tasks.Actions.Controls._children">
      <Button Id="Ribbon.Tasks.Actions.ActionButton"
              Alt="Perform an action for task items."
              Sequence="10"
              Command="ActionButtonCommand"
              LabelText="Action Button"
              TemplateAlias="o1"
              Image32by32="/_layouts/15/ActionRibbon/img/action-32x32.png"
              Image16by16="/_layouts/15/ActionRibbon/img/delete-all-16x16.png" />
    </CommandUIDefinition>
  </CommandUIDefinitions>
  <CommandUIHandlers>
    <CommandUIHandler Command="ActionButtonCommand" CommandAction="javascript:alert('Whoa..! You performed an action!');">
    </CommandUIHandler>
  </CommandUIHandlers>
 </CommandUIExtension>
</CustomAction>
```